# Cannot deploy to Cloud Run, `Internal error encountered`, suggestions?

Tags: google-cloud-run

I can't deploy to Cloud Run, via `gcloud` CLI nor the GCP web console. Both give very unhelpful errors.

Here is the output from the `gcloud` CLI:

```
Deploying container to Cloud Run service [ihsw-nginx] in project [xxx] region [us-central1]
X Deploying new service...
  . Creating Revision...
  . Routing traffic...
Deployment failed
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.run.deploy) INTERNAL: Internal error encountered.
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Here is the repository being used, there is a `cloudbuild.yaml` for pushing to the Container Registry: https://github.com/ihsw/nginx

(Even though it says `nginx`, it's in fact a Node app.)

Comment: Are there any errors logged through Stackdriver logging?

Comment: No errors. That is what is so confusing about this. Switching logging verbosity to `--verbosity debug` reports that accessing `https://us-central1-run.googleapis.com/apis/serving.knative.dev/v1alpha1/namespaces/xxx/services?alt=json` returns a 500 (Internal Server Error) HTTP response code.

Comment: This looks like a bug in the Cloud Run API, if you are consistently seeing this, please contact Google Cloud Support.

Comment: @AhmetB-Google I don't have a support plan purchased. Can I still contact GCP Cloud Support without a support plan?

Comment: Are you consistently reproduce the issue? If so, I may be able to provide an email address to send your project ID etc to take a look.

Comment: @AhmetB-Google yes, it happens every time I try to deploy a Cloud Run service. Any help would be appreciated and I would be happy to send my project ID to whomever you ask.

Answer (score 1):

i don't know if is the same problem, but i solved that way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60084251/7466829

In my case, is really a CloudRun bug.

Answer (score 0):

Your repo works for me.

Pre-req's for this to work (and I assume you're there already) are:

- `gcloud services enable [cloudbuild|run].googleapis.com --project=${PROJECT}`
- Billing enabled (I assume)
- The cloudbuild service account needs:

  - `roles/cloudbuild.builds.builder` (default)
  - `roles/storage.objectCreator`
  - `roles/run.admin`
  - `roles/iam.serviceAccountUser`

Generally you can submit issues at Google's [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues).

If the issue persists, I'd recommend filing under [`Cloud SDK`](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187143&template=800102)

Comment: Thank you for your deply DazWilkin, I have verified that those services are enabled, billing is enabled, and that the cloudbuild service account has those roles. However, that said, the issue remains present and reliably reproducible.

Comment: I recommend filng an issue on the issue tracker. Have you tried running your deploy locally? Either the entire Cloud Build or just the Cloud Run deployment?

Comment: Running `gcloud beta run deploy` fails similarly, the Cloud Build steps that build the container image and push to GCR finish succesfully but the `gcloud run deploy` fails  too.

Comment: You wanna try with my copy of your image? Temporarily available: docker pull gcr.io/dazwilkin-190415-trillian/nginx@sha256:f9e69f836c41d2f12a575f59744134b3464fe1bc7a8a13bea369e0fed3af10b1 you should (!?) be able to confirm the hash matches yours.

Comment: The container image runs fine, it's just that Cloud Run doesn't deploy for me. I think I'm missing the Cloud Run service account but I don't know how to create it.

Comment: You don't create it. It's Google-created|assigned and should be provisioned when you enable(d) the Cloud Run service. I didn't think to ask what role your credentials have in the project. Presumably you've reviewed this: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/iam/roles#additional-configuration

Comment: GCP did not create the Cloud Run service account when I enabled the Cloud Run service. Yes I have reviewed the Cloud Run IAM docs.

Comment: Aha! Have you tried disabling and re-enabling? You could try a different (new) project if this is just for testing. Otherwise, I think we're still at filing an issue with issue tracker to get some form of support.

Comment: I have repeatedly disabled and re-enabled the Cloud Run API but I cannot disable the Compute Engine API as I have VMs running on it now. I will try this in a new project. EDIT: I have verified that Cloud Run works on this new project, and that new project has the Default compute engine service account.