# Can not deploy any revisions (old or first) to Cloud Run

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

"Cloud Run error: Internal system error."
This errors and only this errors keeps coming when trying to deploy a revision (new or first)

What is going on with Cloud Run?

Their page won't load from GCP (though I can get in via google search) and I cannot deploy any revision without getting this error

The container works locally

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be a temporary issue in the platform. You can check it in [google cloud status webpage](https://status.cloud.google.com/).

> We've received a report of an issue with Cloud Run.

Both Cloud Run and Cloud Source Repository seems to be affected.

Usually google's team is quick in fixing whatever happened, you can find more info [here](https://status.cloud.google.com/incident/cloud-run) as soon as something starts to move :)

Comment: This has been fixed, deployments should work fine now

Comment: Since yesterday, the same error happens when i'm trying deploy on cloud run:
`Cloud Run error: Internal system error. Invalid ENTRYPOINT.`

Answer (score 1):

Change the Docker image `ENTRYPOINT` value or set those fields:

[image: screenshot from cloud run deploy]